# Selenium Webdriver and Jupyter Notebook. find_elements_by_xpath not working in same cell

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I am running the code below to scrape some data from wunderground.com.

```
lookup_URL = 'https://www.wunderground.com/hourly/us/ny/new-york-city/date/2020-07-28.html'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions();
options.headless = False

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe', options = options)

driver.get(lookup_URL)
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[@class="mat-cell cdk-cell cdk-column-liquidPrecipitation mat-column-liquidPrecipitation ng-star-inserted"]')
```

If I run that code in a single cell, I get an empty list for `rows`.

However, if I run this line `rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(.......)` afterwards in a different cell, I get exactly the data I needed.

The problem is that I need to execute the script all at once, not in two parts.

Does anyone know why is that happening? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This just indicates that your page is doing some AJAX call and it doesn't have enough wait between `driver.get` and `find_elements_by_xpath`. If you put some sleep it will work in the same cell. Better way is to EC (ExpectedConditions)

Comment: Thank you @TarunLalwani this is what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you need wait.

```
rows = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, 'xpath_here')))
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: Sorry for the delay @frianH. This is exactly what I needed thank you very much!